# mysql display calculated average for all rows

Tags: php, mysql, math, average, rating

Table structure

```
rating.post_id
rating.user_id
rating.rate_like
rating.rate_dislike
```

Sample data:

```
rating.post_id = 1
rating.user_id = 1
rating.rate_like = 1
rating.rate_dislike = 0

rating.post_id = 1
rating.user_id = 2
rating.rate_like = 1
rating.rate_dislike = 0

rating.post_id = 1
rating.user_id = 3
rating.rate_like = 0
rating.rate_dislike = 1
```

Given the structure above, post 1 is rated by user 1, 2 and 3 wherein users 1 and 2 voted for like while user 3 voted for dislike.

With that, how to get the average where rating is a five(5) star rating?

Formula:
`(((total rate_like / total votes) * 100) * 0.5) / 10 = Rate (round to nearest .5)`

Example:
`(((2/3) * 100) * 0.5) / 10 = 3.33 (round to 3.5)`

Rate would be 3.5 out of 5 stars

Expected mysql output would be:

```
post_id = 1
rate_like = 2
rate_dislike = 1
total_rating = 3.5
```

Here's what I've done with the sql but I have no idea how to make it into one sql statement only.

This gets the average:

`select round(round((((sum(rate_like) / (sum(rate_like) + sum(rate_dislike)) * 100) * 0.5) / 10) * 2) / 2, 1) from rating group by post_id`

In which should be merge into this statement:

`SELECT post_id, sum(rate_like), sum(rate_dislike), (sum(rate_like) + sum(rate_dislike)) from rating group by post_id`

Merging the two statements gives an error of `subquery returns more than 1 row`:

`SELECT post_id, sum(rate_like), sum(rate_dislike), (sum(rate_like) + sum(rate_dislike)), (select round(round((((sum(rate_like) / (sum(rate_like) + sum(rate_dislike)) * 100) * 0.5) / 10) * 2) / 2, 1) from rating group by post_id) from rating group by post_id`

Adding a `where` clause on both `select` statements solves the issue but it is needed to display multiple rows instead.

Comment: I'm confused, you ask a question, and then provide a formula answering your question. What are you trying to get help with? Nobody here is going to write the code for you.

Comment: Just needed the sql statement.

Comment: What did you try already? Can you post the SQL statement you are working on that failed?

Comment: Apologies, should have included it in my question.. I've updated my question and included the sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... was able to figure this out. Subquery is used as a joined table instead of a column.

`SELECT 
    rating.post_id,
    sum(rate_like), 
    sum(rate_dislike), 
    (sum(rate_like) + sum(rate_dislike)),
    column_rating
from rating
inner join (
    select 
        post_id, 
        round(round((((sum(rate_like) / (sum(rate_like) + sum(rate_dislike)) * 100) * 0.5) / 10) * 2) / 2, 1) as column_rating
    from rating group by post_id
) as rating_table
on rating.post_id = rating_table.post_id
group by rating.post_id`